# Arima function in forecast package and predict()

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

I have a series named `Price` with 30 observations:

```
Price
[1] 0.2946825 0.2962453 0.2995118 0.3250501 0.3413176 0.3212861 0.3285121
 [8] 0.3223009 0.3219386 0.3049079 0.3046129 0.2912507 0.2947570 0.2947570
[15] 0.2930427 0.2877321 0.2875071 0.2929681 0.2890062 0.2896052 0.2863812
[22] 0.2826947 0.2799019 0.2758878 0.2742928 0.2847277 0.2839752 0.2919977
[29] 0.2797507 0.2739887
```

I run this command `Prediction_Price_30 <-predict(Arima((Price[1:29]),order=c(1,1,0)),n.ahea=1)` in order to generate an Arima(1,1,0) model using totally 29 observation and to predict 30th one with "one ahead".

The result is `0.2805374`

```
Time Series:
Start = 30 
End = 30 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0.2805374
```

I was wondering how `predict` function conduct the prediction. Does it insert the 29th actual observation (by differencing) in to the generated ARIMA (1,1,0) model and calculate the prediction of 30th value?

```
summary(Arima((Price[1:29]),order=c(1,1,0)))
Series: (Price[1:29]) 
ARIMA(1,1,0)                    

Coefficients:
          ar1
      -0.0662
s.e.   0.1910

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0001622:  log likelihood=82.96
AIC=-161.91   AICc=-161.43   BIC=-159.25

Training set error measures:
                        ME       RMSE         MAE         MPE      MAPE
Training set -0.0006482771 0.01228864 0.008384534 -0.05293643 0.6172495
                  MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.9673133 0.003299951
```

I mean if `Price_prediction30 = -0.0662*(Price_actual29 - Price_actual28)`?

Comment: I think this question fits better at http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question should be asked in Cross-validate.

However, to answer your question. When you specify d = 1 , you suppose that the difference between two succesive value of ''y'' is constant.

```
Ŷt  =  μ  + Yt-1  +  ϕ1 (Yt-1 - Yt-2)
```

Comment: So, by this formula `Ŷ30  =  μ  + 0.2797507  +  (-0.0662) * (0.2797507 - 0.2919977)`? But how to reach the `μ`?